# can't detect the archtitcture of a file

Tags: binary-diagnosis

i extracted a file from a .JPEG with outguess the file extension is .data i tried to identify the file type but the result is application/octet-stream  and i can't figure which extension is it even with file command or online file identifier.[hex_view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HoMk6.png)[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HoMk6.png)

Comment: Show the hexadecimal view.

Comment: application/octet-stream means the signature didn't match any known file type. Maybe you didn't extract it correctly? What sort of file were you expecting and how did you know where to start and end extraction?

Comment: i found a file inside a jpeg , it was secured with password using outguess @MegaTonnage

Comment: the file extension .data

Comment: Ok.. so if you know the password then the file should decrypt successfully, but if you get it wrong then you get what you have here... still encrypted content.